# PHP & Javascript can't pass var values with onClick in divs

Tags: javascript, php

i have a problem with Javascript as im trying to get a variable, i set up an onClick() with js and set everything else up with php.Now with js i have the function given below, but it won't pass the id to the js.Any possible ways of doing it? 
--Shortened question: When i alert the id it says undefined, are there any other ways of doing this?

I know that there might be more articles out there with similar problems as mine and might have been answered & solved but i'm pretty sure they won't have the solution to this question because i've searched a lot.

Any questions will be answered as fast as possible!

```
 $dalert ="'salert'";
  $result = '<div class="alert alert-success" style="width:600px; cursor: default;" id="salert"><strong>Login successful! </strong>Welcome <strong>'.$_SESSION['username'].'</strong>! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clAlert('.@$dalert.');" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>';
```

//JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 //Alert remove animation
 function clAlert(id){
 asd=0;

 alert(id);
  $('#'+id).fadeTo(50,100).slideUp(500, function(){
   $('#'+id).slideUp(500);
  });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Please use `var`, `let` or `const` (don't use `var`) when declaring variables. Also, why is there a lone `id;` there?

Comment: What does the generated markup look like? What's the value of `$dalert`?

Comment: Check the resulting html. You need to have you id as a string, so it should be quoted. try this: onClick="clAlert(\''.@$dalert.'\');"

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for mentioning the id; i wanted to delete it my bad, sorry! Also where do you want me to use those?

Comment: @FelixKling The dalert value is pre-set from me, and the value is 'salert'

Comment: @faster i'll try it right now and i'll come back to you as soon as possible!

Comment: That means your markup generates the code `clAlert(salert)`. Does that look right to you?

Comment: No, but the value i set it to be is clAlert('salert'); because the $dalert value is $dalert=" 'salert' "; @FelixKling

Comment: Ah well, then it should work just fine.

Comment: When i managed to make it do the alert it just said undefined in the alert @FelixKling

Comment: @faster no could not set it up, might have you done a typo? Else no, it does not work, thanks though!

Comment: Putting quotes in variable is not good practice, working as I suggested:  $dalert ="salert";
  $result = '<div class="alert alert-success" style="width:600px; cursor: default;" id="salert"><strong>Login successful! </strong>Welcome <strong>'.$_SESSION['username'].'</strong>! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick="clAlert(\''.@$dalert.'\');" aria-hidden="true">click here to get id</span></div>';

Answer (score 0):

Just changed from $dalert="salert" to $dalert="'salert'"